# C++/CLI Syntax error. It's been a long day and my brain isn't functioning correctly

Tags: visual-c++, syntax, c++-cli

Can anybody see an error with this? The error I get is:

> 1>MainForm.cpp(71): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> 1>MainForm.cpp(72): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>MainForm.cpp(75): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
>
> 1>MainForm.cpp(75): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> 1>MainForm.cpp(76): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Code:

```
if (oMail->From->ToString()->Contains("email@gmail.com")) //Compare to whitelist
{
                mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Accepted!", "You are on the whitelist for this server.");
}
else if () //Compare to blacklist
{
                mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Rejected!", "You are on the blacklist for this server.");
}
else () // Else do Default Behavior
{
    if (UserSettings::TheInstance2->defaultBehavior->ToString() == "Accept")
    {
                mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Accepted!", "Accepted");
    }
    else if (UserSettings::TheInstance2->defaultBehavior->ToString() == "Accept (And add to Whitelist)")
    {
                mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Accepted!", "You have been added to the whitelist for this server!");
    }
    else if (UserSettings::TheInstance2->defaultBehavior->ToString() == "Reject")
    {
                mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Rejected!", "The server admin has set the server to reject non-whitelisted addresses.");
    }
    else if (UserSettings::TheInstance2->defaultBehavior->ToString() == "Reject (And add to Blacklist)")
    {
        mailSend::sendMail("email@gmail.com", "Commands Rejected!", "The server admin has set the server to add rejected addresses to the blacklist. You are now on it.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code says:

```
else if ()
```

Surely this is an error.

Comment: Why is this an error? I will be adding to this later, it's just a skeleton at the minute.

Comment: @Alex - Condition to evaluate should definitely be provided. If you are compiling a program, it should obey the syntactic rules of the language. There is nothing like skeleton.

Comment: @Alex -- it's an error because the language requires that there be an actual condition there.  The compiler doesn't know it's only a skeleton :)

Answer (score 6):

```
 else () 
   // ^^ Remove this.
 {
      // ....
 }
```

`else` statement shouldnot have `()`

Answer (score 2):

```
 else if ()
 ...                                                               
 else ()
```

Yup, time to take a break.